# The complement of a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: general-topology

On twitter I found this image:
[image]

A friend noticed though that if we consider as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $V=\{x^2+y^2<1, z=0\}$ which has dimension $2$ then $\mathbb{R}^3 - V$ is not disconnected when it should according to the image; in fact it should be homeomorphic to $S^0 \times \mathbb{R}^3 = \{-1,1\} \times \mathbb{R^3}$. This led us to believe that either the image is false or "subspace" refers to something else than a simple subspace with the subspace topology. Does anyone have the source for this theorem and can anybody shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that the author is talking about *vector* subspaces here.